# Ошибки в употреблении деепричастных оборотов

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

В пособиях для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому часто пишут, что употребление деепричастного оборота в безличном предложении - грамматическая ошибка. А что по этому поводу думают авторы авторитетных изданий? И действительно ли неграмотно построение такого предложения? Если да, как бы вы его перестроили? Включили бы грамматическую основу *мы думали*?

*Обладая запасом в несколько минут, приходилось думать быстро, ведь прозябать лишний час на выселках не хотелось.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Обладая запасом в несколько минут, приходилось думать быстро, ведь прозябать лишний час на выселках не хотелось.*

Предложение корректно.

Ср. с примером **[у Розенталя](https://rozental.gramatik.ru/xlviii-parallelnye-sintaksicheskie-konstrukcii/ss-212-deeprichastnye-oboroty?ysclid=lkva0qimka129493847)**:

> **§ 212**… В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:
>
> <…>
>
> 2. **в безличном предложении при инфинитиве**, например:
>
> ***Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.***

Comment: Спасибо! Смотрела у него другой справочник.